# Probability - How to treat simultaneous draws

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am kind of confused with a question I am trying to solve. I am confused with "simultaneous draws" for example I have a bag of two objects, $a$ and $b$ and I have $n$ objects of type $a$ and $m$ objects of type $b$.

When we say we draw simultaneously two objects from the bag, is it equivalent to drawing twice without repetition (hyper geometric)?

Comment: Drawing twice without *replacement*.

Comment: Observe that simultaneous draw is the same that draw one by one sequentially. This imply that the random variables that represent each draw are conditioned by the previous draws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an urn containing $n$ red balls and $m$ green balls (just simplified a little).

Now you are said to draw $2$ balls Simultaneously:

In this, first think logically, you are picking $2$ balls simultaneously.In this process, when you touched first one, i.e. you have selected one ball, obviously you are not gonna pick it again, this works same as drawing first ball out of the urn and keeping it aside, as in both the cases you have chosen one ball and going to chose another one from a total of $n+m-1$ balls.So, although you were picking $2$ balls simultaneously, it worked same as picking one by one without replacement.

Now, Mathematically :

When you are going to draw two balls Simultaneously, total number of ways will be -

$${n+m}\choose {2}$$
Another case, when you're gonna draw one by one with replacement,

In first draw, suppose you select ball 
'$i$' total number of ways will be $(n+m)$

In second draw, suppose you select ball '$j$', total number of ways will be $(n+m-1)$ (since we have already selected one ball)

So total number of ways will be

$$\frac{(n+m)(n+m-1)}{2} = \binom{n+m}{2}$$

(I have divided by $2$ since order of
 $i$ and $j$ doesn't matter.)

Which is same as first case!